# DIV float:right with no text wrapping

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a pseudo table of three columns in CSS/HTML:

Columns:

- Long text field, text-align:left
- Variable text field, text-align: right
- Fixed text field, text-align: right

[image]

With short text everything displays correctly.. but if the first column or the second column get too big the text is wrapped:

[image]

What I want is for the first row to overflow with an ellipse so that it appears like this:

[image]

But I can't seem to get the CSS right. Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="filename">First column with some short text</div>
    <div class="download">Download</div>
    <div class="attributes">[Some attributes]</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="filename">First column with some more short text</div>
    <div class="download">Download</div>
    <div class="attributes">[Some attributes]</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="filename">Last row with longer text should be clipped but is not being</div>
    <div class="download">Download</div>
    <div class="attributes">[Attributes, Are, Different]</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div
{
    font-family: arial;
}

.row
{
    width: 600px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px;
}

.row div
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.filename
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

.attributes
{
    float: right;
}

.download
{
    float: right;
}

.attributes,
.download
{
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nLACS/8/

Can anyone suggest the best way of making the first column overflow so that the second two columns do not wrap down below keeping in mind that the second column can also be variable length as well?

Comment: do you want to implement this using divs only or can you use table structure as well?

Comment: I'd prefer DIV if possible but table would be OK

Comment: I think the problem with table would be that all rows would be clipped at the same point.. where ideally rows with different attributes should be clipped at different points depending on the length of the attributes column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about flex solution? The only concern is browser support, but if no need for outdated browsers, you can use this nice feature.

[image: flex demo]

CSS:

```
.row
{
    width: 600px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
}


.filename
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    max-width: 400px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px dotted white;
    margin: 2px;
}

.attributes
{
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    text-align: right;
    display: -moz-flex-inline-block;
    display: flex-inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px dotted white;
    margin: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.download
{
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    display: -moz-flex-inline-block;
    display: flex-inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px dotted white;
    margin: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nLACS/10/

Margins, paddings, borders are thre just for demo.

Comment: fantastic, just what I needed. I have not seen these flex-grow attributes before :)

Comment: You're welcome! It's a really good doc to check:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Please, if you're going to be posting Flexbox solutions, *at least get the prefixes right*.  Also, there's no `flex-inline-block` property.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go with `display:table` and `table-cell` as following:

**html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="filename">First column with some short text</div>
    <div class="tabletow">
        <div class="download">Download</div>
        <div class="attributes">[Some attributes]</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="filename">First column with some more short text</div>
    <div class="tabletow">
        <div class="download">Download</div>
        <div class="attributes">[Some attributes]</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="filename">Last row with longer text should be clipped but i...</div>
    <div class="tabletow">
        <div class="download">Download</div>
        <div class="attributes">[Attributes, Are, Different]</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
div
{
    font-family: arial;
}

.row
{
    width: 600px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px;
    display:table;
}

.filename
{
   display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
    max-width: 250px;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    float:left;
}
.tabletow{
    display:table;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}

.tabletow > div{
    max-width:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.download{
    width:25%;
}

.attributes,
.download
{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLACS/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi as I had commented earlier I have implemented in table elements in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Cp2B/)

HTML

```
<table border=1 frame=hsides rules=rows>
<tr class="rows">
    <td class="column1">
        First column with some short sdsadakjsdhajdhjkashdajskdhajskdhkatext
    </td>
    <td  class="column2">
        Download
    </td>
    <td  class="column3">
        [Some attributes]
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="rows">
    <td class="column1">
        First column with some short sdsadakjsdhajdhjkashdajskdhajskdhkatext
    </td>
    <td  class="column2">
        Download
    </td>
    <td  class="column3">
        [Some attributes]
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="rows">
    <td class="column1">
        First column with some short sdsadakjsdhajdhjkashdajskdhajskdhkatext
    </td>
    <td  class="column2">
        Download
    </td>
    <td  class="column3">
        [Some attributes]
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr { 
   border: solid;
   border-color:white;
   border-width: 5px 0;
}
.column1,.column3 {
   width:25%;
   padding-bottom: 1em;
}
.column1{
   width:50%;
}

.rows{
   background-color: red;
}
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Cp2B/1/)

Comment: seems to be wrapping in Chrome.. the idea is that the columns overflow without wrapping.

Comment: Hi added an updated fiddle so you have the old and the new fiddle in the same answer. Hope that helps